# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator not outputting all keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, recursiveiterator

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
$array = array(
  1 => null,
  2 => array(
    3 => null,
    4 => array(
      5 => null,
    ),
    6 => array(
      7 => null,
    ),
  )
);
```

If I use the following code to iterate over the array

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.' ';
}
```

it only outputs the keys with no arrays assigned to them. I.e.

```
1 3 5 7
```

How can I get it to include all of the keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to set the mode right. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php):

> RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST - Lists leaves **and parents** in iteration with parents coming first.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
                                          , RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Comment: seems to work: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ed757e1a0ac69ada40b7ac48ba7996e6389bc22

Comment: `SELF_FIRST` and `CHILD_FIRST` modes will both give the non-leaf items (in your case, the arrays), whereas the default `LEAVES_ONLY` mode does not.